# BST Implementation in Python Bugs

Tags: python, insert, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a BST in Python. I am getting an error on the insert function: "Node object has no attribute insert." Is there a reason I cannot call the insert function on the Node object I have defined?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right        
    def setdata(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def hasLeft(self):
        return self.left 
    def hasRight(self):
        return self.right
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root:
            self._insert(data, self.root)
        else:
            self.root=Node(data)

    def _insert(self, data, curr):
        if data<curr.data:
            if curr.hasLeft:
                self._insert(data, curr.left)
            else:
                curr.left=Node(data)
        if data>self.data:
            if self.hasRight:
                self._insert(data, curr.right)
            else:
                curr.right=Node(data)
root = Node(2)
root.insert(1)
root.insert(3)

print root
print root.left
```

Comment: the error belongs to which line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the statements `root = Node(2)` and `root.insert(1)`. You are calling the `insert` method in a `Node` instance when you probably meant a `BST`.

The following should probably work:

```
tree = BST()
tree.insert(2)
```